# Decodificar na Base 64 não considera "Ç"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho os seguintes trechos de código:

```
window.btoa(CodAcabamento) //Codifica meu código para enviar para a WebApi

string CodAcabamentoDes = Base64Decode(CodAcabamento); //Decodifica meu código para realizar buscas no bd

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
```

Porém o `Base64Decode` não considera o `Ç`, é problema com a `Base` que estou usando ou algum outro problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo de como esta no Banco de Dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Informação complementar:

Foi necessário usar a `Base64`, devido ao fato de que uso `Route` e alguns código recebem `/`, o que dá problema.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do Base64

Comment: Desculpe, essa parte quem fez foi um colega de serviço, pois possuem alguns códigos que possuem caracteres especiais e estava me dando problema, segundo meu colega isso foi necessário

Comment: Mostre um exemplo de como a string está no banco de dados

Comment: Acrescentei na pergunta @LeandroAngelo

Comment: O correto não seria usar base 64, se você está passando caracteres especiais na rota via GET você precisa fazer é um URL encode e decode (por conta da `/`)

Comment: Não tem como saber o erro sem entender o que faz o método `Base64Decode`

Comment: Ah, perdão, esqueci de postar o método @LINQ

Comment: @LeandroAngelo vou pesquisar como posso fazer isso e tentar alterar

Comment: @JeffHenrique Vou escrever uma resposta.

Comment: Ok,. estou no aguardo

Comment: Base64 da forma que aplicou não tem sentido (ao menos pra mim), eu suponho que base64 seja para **evitar perdas** ao transportar dados BINÁRIOS e só, como por exemplo conteudo de imagens. Se a ideia é criar um IDs que não sejam numeros para suas URLs seria melhor usar algo como GUID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não faz o mínimo sentido o uso de Base64 aí. Minha dica é reescrever da forma correta.

Além disso, é importante entender a causa do problema. Bem, muito provavelmente, a representação em Base64 que está chegando à aplicação *backend* é referente ao caracter `ç` "codificado" em Windows-1252.

No seu código, você assume que a codificação da string é UTF-8. Por isso o problema.

Tenha em mente que [**não faz nenhum sentido ter uma *string* sem saber que codificação ela usa**.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

A adaptação do seu código para funcionar neste caso em específico seria algo como:

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
{
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);

    var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); // Windows-1252
    return enc.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, funcionou, irei ler o artigo que me mandou, agradeço